# How to assert an entire dataframe contains only numeric dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert

How can I most easily assert an entire dataframe contains only numeric dtypes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use undocumented private methods, that might change, you can try this:

```
len(df.columns) == len(df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns)
```

or

```
all(np.issubdtype(dtype, np.number) for dtype in df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you have following dataframe, then we using `_is_numeric_mixed_type`

```
    ID  value
0   A1     11
2   A2     13
4   A3     15
6   B1     21
8   B2     23
10  B3     25
12  C1     31
14  C2     33
16  C3     35
s._is_numeric_mixed_type
Out[847]: False
```

Comment: Just an FYI @BirdLaw, the underlying code for this is just `all([block.is_numeric for block in df._data.blocks])`.  That would only change if DataFrame internals themselves changed, probably.